# Serializing a Python Object

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, sparse-matrix

Hi I have a class that looks like so. Due to some down stream constraints a "Dataset" object must be saved into a single file. Usually I would use `sparse.save_npz` and save a file for `X` and save a json file for `meta_data` (see `save_to_dir`). I'm wondering how I can go about saving "Dataset" into a single file. I'm aware of pickling but pickling seems to take way to long when the sparse matrix gets large. Is there a clever way in which I can take bytes of `X.indptr, X.indices, X.data` arrays and append them with the bytes of `meta_data` and somehow save into a single file? or another approach?

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import json
from pathlib import Path

class Dataset: 
    def __init__(self, X: sparse.csr_matrix, meta_data: dict):
        self.X = X
        self.meta_data = meta_data

    def save_to_single_file(self, dest_file: str) -> None: 
        # TODO
    
    def save_to_dir(self, dir_name: str) -> None:
       save_dir = Path(dir_name)
       sparse.save_npz(self.X, save_dir / "X.npz")
       
       with open(save_dir / "meta_data.json", "w") as f:
           json.dump(self.meta_data, f)
```

Comment: `save_npz` is python which you can read.  It saves those arrays as npy files in a npz archive.  pickle for a numpy array is its npy save.

Comment: You can pack everything into an h5 file. That's specifically for this problem. Try looking at the AnnData package as well.